# JPA - ElementCollection of foreign key

Tags: java, jpa

I try to map, in an entity A, a `Set<String>` with each string referring to primary key of entities B.

I insist: **It must be the reference to the key. Not the entire entity**... I allready know how to make a @ManyToOne, @OneToMany, and so on ... ;)

For example:

```
@Entity
public class A {

    (...)

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    // Here is the problem: I want the siren as a foreign key of entity B
    @ElementCollection
    private Set<String> b_ids;

    (...)

}

@Entity
public class B {

    (...)

    @Id
    private String id;

    (...)

}
```

**EDIT:**
I try to reformulate the question: Is there a way to store a Set of the only id of an entity, but with link (and check and control as for ManyToMany and so on) to the foreign key?

Comment: I find it really hard to understand what you are asking for. Could you provide something of an example showing what you would like to achieve?

Comment: As per all JPA docs, the `ElementCollection` will map to a separate table, with one column being FK back to the owner table, and another column being the String element. End of. Where your `B` comes into that is for you to decide, but you do NOT store "id" fields as arbitrary Strings in JPA. This is object-oriented programming ...

Comment: Ok. But, then, is there a way to map only the B ids in a Set with other annotations? As it's possible to have a column in my database with foreignkey from B, I'll hope JPA is able to generate table with this foreign key.

Comment: You can map **relations** to `B` objects (and that can be represented as a FK). An "id" does not exist on its own in an object-oriented system

Answer (score 2):

It should work with a couple of additional annotations. Source: https://javabydeveloper.com/mapping-collection-of-basic-value-types-jpa-with-hibernate/

```
@Entity
public class A {

    (...)

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="B", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id"))
    @Column(name="id")
    private Set<String> b_ids;

    (...)

}
```

So the CollectionTable and Column annotations were added.

Comment: The real matter is to link with the primary key of B. I allready know how to map a collection of basic...

Comment: @Mohicane A primary key is nothing more than a column with special attention. Meanwhile you say nothing about trying out the additional annotations to see if that works or not.

Comment: I have another exception: `A Foreign key refering A from B has the wrong number of column.`
But I'm still skeptical. You mean that, one of your annotation here do the job??? ElementCollection map the basics, CollectionTable manage the configuration of the table generated (but don't make link with table B) and Column name the column in the table generated... I know what I insert in my Set in the java code, but I still try to make JPA manage the foreign key.

Comment: `@Column(name="id")` will do you no good, that will only conflict with the other column which is actually named "id", rather than your element collection which is not a column

Comment: Thank you mate, `joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id")` here was my problem